# Hour Minute Conversion in SQL

Tags: sql

I have 3 value in in time like 10.98  , 10.97, 11.0 hour. I wrote aquery  as

```
select d.EmployeeID, 
      ( (sum (floor(d.OTHour))+ floor(((sum(d.OTHour-floor(d.OTHour)))*100)/60))
        + cast(((cast(((sum(d.OTHour-floor(d.OTHour)))*100)as int))%60) as float)/100
      ) As TotalOT  
from DailyAttnProcess d 
where d.ShiftID in ( select distinct shiftID 
                            from ShiftTerm st, ShiftTermDetail std, Term t 
                            where st.ShiftTermID=std.ShiftTermID 
                                  and std.TermID=t.TermID and t.TermID=1) 
and d.AttnDate between '01 Oct 2016' and '31 Oct 2016' 
AND d.EmployeeID=9072  
Group By  d.EmployeeID
```

The result i get is 34.15 but the actual result should 32.57 .  any one please help me by correcting this . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us minimized table data producing the wrong result.

Comment: Haw can anyone answer this without sample input, expected output, and DDL? Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The data you show is not a time, it's like a float with an integer part of hours and a fractional hour (60 minutes = 1).

Based on your data and the expected result of `32.57` (hours & **minutes**?) you simply need to sum and multiply the fractional part of the result times 0.6:

```
  floor(sum(d.OTHour))     -- full hours
+ (sum(d.OTHour) % 1)*0.6) -- fractional part in minutes
```

Of course this would be much easier if the time was stored as a `TIME` and not as float.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT minutes / 60 + (minutes % 60) / 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values are not time values but float values. `10.5` would mean `10:30` and `10.75` was `10:45`.

You can add your float values just *as is* and then calculate a value representing your seconds:

(This code is a bit to *much*, just to show the principles)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(HourWithFraction FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(10.98),(10.97),(11.0);

WITH SummedUp AS
(
    SELECT SUM(HourWithFraction) AS SumOfTimes
    FROM @tbl
)
,InParts AS
(
    SELECT CAST(SumOfTimes AS INT) AS HourPart
          ,SumOfTimes - CAST(SumOfTimes AS INT) AS MinuteFraction 
    FROM SummedUp
)
SELECT HourPart
      ,MinuteFraction
      ,MinuteFraction * 0.6 AS SecondPart
      ,CAST(HourPart AS varchar(10)) + ':' + REPLACE(STR(MinuteFraction * 60,2),' ','0') AS FormattedTime
FROM InParts;
```

The usage of `REPLACE` and `STR` is there to ensure padding with `0` if the second value has got one digit only.

The result

```
HourPart    MinuteFraction  SecondPart  FormattedTime
32          0,950000000000  0,57000000  32:57
```

Comment: Thank you 
#shnugo

Comment: @AmirulIslam As you are rather new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you*, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!